# Scheme R5RS: defining let expression

Tags: scheme, racket, r5rs

I was wondering how you would go about defining your own let expression in Scheme (I'm very new to scheme). I want it to look like (mylet id expr1 expr2) where id is bound to expr1's value and used in expr2. I think it would be something along the lines of:

```scm
(define (mylet x a body) 
  ((lambda (x) body) a) )
```

but that isn't working.

When I try

```scm
(mylet x 4 (* x 4))
```

I get the following error:

```
x: undefined; cannot reference undefined identifier.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`let` is actually a macro. You cannot define this as a procedure. Since you're using Racket, try this:

```
(define-syntax-rule (mylet x a body)
  ((lambda (x) body) a))
```

That looks almost like your original code, but using `define-syntax-rule` instead of `define`. ;-) That `define-syntax-rule` is actually a shortcut for the following full macro:

```
(define-syntax mylet
  (syntax-rules ()
    ((_ x a body)
     ((lambda (x) body) a))))
```

Indeed, you can even define the "standard" `let` macro (minus named `let`) this way:

```
(define-syntax-rule (let ((id val) ...) body ...)
  ((lambda (id ...) body ...) val ...))
```

Note the use of the ellipses (`...`). This allows zero or more forms; in this case, it allows `let` to contain multiple body forms.